# Show warning when deleting rows with CASCADE deletes

Tags: mysql, sql, datagrip

Is there any option (or even DB client) to require a confirmation when deleting a row for CASCADE deletes. For example:

> DELETE FROM catalogs WHERE id=1
>
> Warning: this will also DELETE CASCADE 92,358 products and 142 catalog_histories. Are you sure? (If so, temporarily turn on ALLOW_CASCADE_DELETES or add WITH CASCADES to query)

I will prefer a solution that doesn't require following particular rules in db schema and works with MySQL. (Alternatively if there is a way to force FK deletes while leaving CASCADE off schema in general then this will also be a good option.)

Comment: DBMS is about data processing, it has no user interaction. All the user interaction should appear at application level with warning messages, confirmation etc.

Comment: if you want to achieve what you requested:, 
1. make a get records/counts first, show on screen for user acceptance, and on OK - delete records.

Comment: @astentx It's perfectly reasonable that MySQL could support an option to support convenience when needed and risk reduction by default. I suspected it wasn't possible but hoping... it's okay for data processing tools to be friendly.

Comment: @EdwinEvans Maybe, but DBMS is a backend, so it's not supposed to allow business users to do some modifications directly inside the database (despite the fact that SQL was developed as "user friendly"). And as your user is allowed to delete something directly inside a database, they should be highly privileged. This in turn assumes that such user is not a curious passerby, but someone with wise intention. It sounds reasonable, but IDE is not a SQL engine itself, so there's no such medium to provide warnings: transaction should finish successfully or should fail, no intermediary states.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in mysql

i tried it a bit https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6575f084b486025a66f6d52a4df9893

but the foreign key restaont has to be enable before you start to delete the row like in the example

So you must run two codes one with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE catalogs(id int PRIMARY KEY);
>
> INSERT INTO catalogs VALUES (1),(2);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE catalogs_sub(id int, cat_id int, 
>
>     FOREIGN KEY (cat_id)
>       REFERENCES catalogs( id)
>       ON DELETE CASCADE
>       )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO catalogs_sub VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,2)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM catalogs_sub
> ```
>
> ```
> id | cat_id
> -: | -----:
>  1 |      1
>  2 |      1
>  3 |      2
>  4 |      2
> ```

> ```
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
> DELETE FROM catalogs WHERE id=1;
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM catalogs
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM catalogs_sub
> ```
>
> ```
> id | cat_id
> -: | -----:
>  1 |      1
>  2 |      1
>  3 |      2
>  4 |      2
> ```

> ```
> DELETE FROM catalogs WHERE id=2;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM catalogs
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM catalogs_sub
> ```
>
> ```
> id | cat_id
> -: | -----:
>  1 |      1
>  2 |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd4c770a7fb6f345fc436f7ee80bc271)*